# Python "triplet" dictionary?

Tags: python

If we have `(a1, b1)` and `(a2, b2)` it's easy to use a dictionary to store the correspondences:

```
dict[a1] = b1
dict[a2] = b2
```

And we can get `(a1, b1)` and `(a2, b2)` back no problem.

But, if we have `(a1, b1, c1)` and `(a2, b2, c2)`, is it possible to get something like:

```
dict[a1] = (b1, c1)
dict[b1] = (a1, c1)
```

Where we can use either `a1` or `b1` to get the triplet `(a1, b1, c2)` back? Does that make sense? I'm not quite sure which datatype to use for this problem. The above would work but there would be duplicate data.

Basically, if I have a triplet, which data type could I use such that I can use either the first or second value to get the triplet back?

Comment: You want to be able to recover the triplet from any of the elements?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon For my specific problem, if I have `a1`, I'd like to know `b1` and `c1`. And if I only have `b1`, I'd need to know `a1` and `c1`. But I'd never have `c1` directly... If that makes sense.

Comment: perfect time to learn how to make your own data types. see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Comment: Quick hint: you would either need a custom mapping type (e.g. a `dict` subclass with `__getitem__` overridden, at the very least) or you would need some custom container type that can wrap each item of your tuples and the tuples themselves such that they have the same `__hash__`. I suspect you might have an X-Y problem though but hard to be sure.

Comment: To what I thought was your main question, there isn't a way to store this without duplicating data unless you do what @Iguananaut explained by overriding the hash possibly to have multiple keys point to the same thing.  If you were concerned with tuple lengths longer than 3 you could refer any key to the ordered key that comes before and after, and therefore return any variable length starting from any position without duplicating more than necessary.

Comment: I think it's an interesting problem. The answers given below are the most obvious but if you wanted to completely avoid duplication you'd have to do some tricks with hashes. I have to say, while it's a neat idea, in 25 years of programming I have never needed a data structure quite like this which is why I suspect an X-Y problem, but who knows stranger things have happened.

Comment: What behavior do you expect/want when values overlap? Are you assuming that a set a1 can never equal a2? Or, for that matter, a1 can't equal b1 or b2?

Comment: Apparently, this type of question needs a basic relational database as been pointed out here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/85842/127240   Consider using `sqlite` module for that. This is basically `SELECT * FROM table_foo WHERE b_value = 'b1';`  which would probably be the same as `SELECT * FROM table_foo WHERE a_value = 'a1';` And if I'm not mistaken a1 and b1 would be composite key for c1

Comment: Is the order of the returned triplet strictly required?  Is `(b1, a1, c1)` ok?

Answer (score 10):

## Solution

You can write your own mapping data-structure which allows to `add` triples, or groups of any size, and recover the group with `__getitem__`.

```
class GroupMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def add(self, group):
        for item in group:
            self.data[item] = group

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data[item]

group = (1, 2, 3)
group_map = GroupMap()

group_map.add(group)

print(group_map[1]) # (1, 2, 3)
```

Notice that this `GroupMap` can be used for groups of any size, not only triples.

The next step in the above would be to extend the class to avoid collisions according to the behaviour you want when a collision occurs.

## Theory

You might wonder if there is a better way to represent groups of connected objects. The answer is not really.

Suppose you have a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) containing *n* vertices. Then for the graph to be connected, you must have at least *n - 1* edges. In the above data-structure, I used *n* entry in the `dict`, meaning the solution is nearly optimal.

Why not use *n - 1* entries if it can be done? Because you would then need to traverse all your graph to recover the whole group. Thus using one more edge allows for *O(1)* lookup, which is a trade-off you probably want to take.

Comment: Wouldn't this still duplicate the information in the same way?

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 Yes, but there is no other way. A connexion between two items must be stored one way of another. Another way to visualize this is that a graph of n items must have at least (n-1) vertices to be connected. Here I use two more than that, but this is to allow fast lookup.

Comment: Yea I understand I just wanted to be clear that we agreed.  I thought the primary element of the question was to reduce duplication which I don't believe can be done either, I just thought your answer turned what the post already said they could do into a class with methods, which is written nicely, but I felt the post already explained they knew how to do what your answer provided and they were looking for other methods.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 Fair point, I edited the answer to explain why we cannot do better than that.

Comment: I agree with your edit and I think beyond just triplets you could get into time vs space complexity comparisons on other methods of traversing a graph possibly if space was a huge concern but at a triplet this is most likely going to be altogether most efficient.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 The problem I see with traversal is that it requires implementing some kind of graph data-structure which 1) slows down everything and 2) is a bit overly complex in my opinion for what we want to achieve.

Comment: Because this interested me I did some size testing and realized that Python is reusing the same object as the value for each of your dictionary keys and not duplicating them at all, so it is for sure size efficient. I did not think it would reuse the same object like that.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 I suppose you mean it reuse the values of the dict and not key. And yes, this is expected, there is no reason Python would copy an object because it is set as item in a dict, this would actually be undesirable.

Comment: It's not immediately clear how your "Theory" section corresponds to concrete implementation. Associative structures correspond to directed graphs, so I think you always need `n` edges to be able to recover the entire structure. Your proposal uses `n` references in a hashtable, + original structure, whereas optimal is to associate `h(x_i)` to `x_(i+1%n)` ie. `n` hashtable entries which themselves form the original structure.

Comment: @moonGoose It does not directly relates to the implementation, it describes a lower bound on how much information must be stored. My goal is to give an intuition, not a rigorous proof, of why there exists no optimization by an order of magnitude and thus that a certain level of duplication is required.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative if you want to subclass `dict` (to get all other methods associated with `dict` like `.get` and whatnot) and *only* get the *other* elements when asked (for some reason). You can make a new dictionary that is all your own

```
class TupleDict(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        assert isinstance(key, tuple)
        for i, e in enumerate(key):
            dict.__setitem__(self, e, key[:i] + key[i+1:] + (value,))
        dict.__setitem__(self, value, key)
```

and then assign any key that is a tuple to a single value (not sure I like this syntax, but we can make it different or use a stand-alone method)

```
d = TriDict()
d[(1,2)] = 4
```

and you will have the result of `__getitem__` return the rest of the tuple not present.

```
>>> print(d[1])
(2, 4)
>>> print(d[2])
(1, 4)
print(d[4])
>>> (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries can store key value pairs only.

You could make your own triplet dictionary however using operator overloading so that when you index with any member of the triplets you get back the other two, maybe something like this:

```
class trictionary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def add(self, group):
        self.data.append(group)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for group in data: #Find the set the key belongs to.
            if key in group:
                return tuple(group)
```

This avoids replicating the data and has the functionality you're looking for at the expense of performance. There may be a better way of doing the same.

Comment: I love "trictionary"

Answer (score 1):

Building on Olivier Melançons answer, I came up with this - in case the position of the value in the tuple matters:

```
class GroupMap:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = {}
        if data:
            self.add(data)

    def add(self, data):
        for idx, key in enumerate(data):
            self.data.setdefault(idx, {})[key] = data

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # lookup in first index
        return self.getby(0, key)

    def getby(self, idx, key):
        return self.data[idx].get(key)


data = ('a', 'b', 'c')
g = GroupMap(data)
more_data = ('b', 'a', 'z')
g.add(more_data)

assert g['a'] == data

assert g.getby(0, 'a') == data
assert g.getby(0, 'b') == more_data
assert g.getby(0, 'c') is None

assert g.getby(1, 'a') == more_data
assert g.getby(1, 'b') == data

assert g.getby(2, 'c') == data
assert g.getby(2, 'z') == more_data

assert id(data) == id(g['a']) == id(g.getby(1, 'b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has examples that deviate from the main question:

> Basically, if I have a triplet, which data type could I use such that I can use either the first or second value to get the triplet back?

A dict. Assign key-value pairs of `element`, `triplet` (see @Olivier Melançon's answer):

**Code**

```
d = {}
for x in triplet:
   d[x] = triplet
```

**Demo**

```
d["a"]
# ('a', 'b', 'c')

d["b"]
# ('a', 'b', 'c')

d["c"]
# ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

The OP requires clarity on preferred behavior in:

- adding elements, e.g. `d[a1] = (b1, c1)` vs. `f((a1, b1, c1))`
- element ordering, e.g. `(a1, b1, c1)` vs. `(b1, a1, c1)`
- duplicate data, e.g. hold `(a1, b1, c1)` three times or combinations of 2-tuple subsets

With these items addressed, more elaborate solutions are possible.